# How to add items to wx.ScrolledPanel?

Tags: python, scroll, wxpython

I want to add dynamically captured images in hierarchical structure (one after one). I want to add them to wx.ScrolledPanel

**ScrolledPanel definition - updated**

```
    self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    #self.sizer.Add(self.hbox)
    self.scroll = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self, id = -1, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = (500, 400), style= wx.SUNKEN_BORDER , name = "Scroll")
    self.scroll.SetupScrolling(10,10,10,10)
    #self.scroll.SetSizer(self.hbox)
    self.sizer.Add(self.scroll)    


   #add to scroll
   images = wx.StaticBitmap(self, id=-1, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                            size=(200,150),
                            style= wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
   images.SetBitmap(bmp)
   self.hbox.Add(images, 1, wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
   self.scroll.SetSizer(self.hbox)
   self.scroll.SetAutoLayout(1)
   self.scroll.SetupScrolling()
   self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
   self.Refresh() 
   self.Layout()
```

- Python 2.6, windows 32bit

After update - I see `scrollpanel` and I add images to sizer. But sizer is not displaying in scrollPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a crude but runnable example of what you want, there is a slight glitch in it thought that I haven't figured out the cause of yet! (You just need to put a thumbnail size jpg called "image.jpg" in the same directory as the script)

```
import wx
import  wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class ImageDlg(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent=parent,title=title, size=wx.DefaultSize)

        self.scrollPnl = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self, -1, size=(200, 200), style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.addBtn = wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_ADD)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_add, self.addBtn)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)       

        self.scrollPnlSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)       
        img = wx.Image("image.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        staticBitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.scrollPnl, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.scrollPnlSizer.Add(staticBitmap, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)

        self.mainSizer.Add(self.addBtn)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.scrollPnl)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainSizer)


    def on_add(self, event):
        img = wx.Image("image.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        staticBitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.scrollPnl, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.scrollPnlSizer.Add(staticBitmap, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
        self.scrollPnl.SetSizer(self.scrollPnlSizer)
        self.scrollPnl.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.scrollPnl.SetupScrolling()  

        self.Refresh()
        self.Layout()

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):     
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        openDlg_btn = wx.Button(self, label="Open Dialog")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBtn)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mainSizer.Add(openDlg_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer)
        self.Centre()

    def onBtn(self, event):
        dlg = ImageDlg(self, title='Image Dialog')
        dlg.SetSize((300,300))

        dlg.CenterOnScreen()
        dlg.ShowModal()  
        dlg.Destroy()


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        TestPanel(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = TestFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: but I want add images to scroll panel because if I add them to self.sizer - my window is getting bigger and bigger

Comment: I make it. In sixth line I Add(self.hbox), but it works not properly. My sizer is getting bigger but now I see scroll (images are added to sizer and scroll panel?)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, If you provide a runnable example of the problem it would be easier to figure out whats wrong, because I cant see anything wrong with what you have, I have similar code that works... Something else in your code may be affecting...

Comment: Ugh looks nasty... I can't tell by the screenshot whats wrong, Ill add the test code that I have, there is is slight glitch in it though that I haven't figured out the cause of yet.

Comment: HAHA, it helps;) I add wx.StaticBitmap to self instead of self.scroll ;) Thanx again!