# Scrolled Panel not working in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

```
 class Frame(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(self):
     wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,-1, "SCSM Observatory Log", size=(700, 700))

         panel = wxScrolledPanel.ScrolledPanel(self,-1, size=(800,10000))
         panel.SetupScrolling()
```

Could someone please explain why this code is not working? I am not getting any errors, but its like the scrolling commands are not being initialized possibly?

Edit: The scrolling works but I have to resize the window and make it smaller to enable the scrolling capabilities. Also, it will not scroll all the way to the bottom.

Edit 2: Apparently the scroll bar only scrolls as far as the vertical size of the frame. So if i set the frame y-size to 1000, it will scroll to 1000. The only problem is that a window that large would be too big for the monitor this is used on. Is there a way to force the scrollbar to go to a distance that is larger than the size of the frame? For example, I would like the window to open with size of (700,700), but I need the scrollbar to go to 1000.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? scrollbar not being shown? if so, is it because nothing is added to scrolledpanel? would this example help troubleshoot? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3583576/566035 what happens if you leave setupscrolling all default with SetupScrolling()?

Comment: I've tried adding a size to the scrolled panel and that didn't work. And yes, the scrollbar is not being shown at all. If i leave setup scrolling as default, i get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it is not working for you, following a sample which works for me.  I like using sized_controls as they handle sizers nicely (in my view).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
print(wx.VERSION_STRING)
import wx.lib.sized_controls as SC


class MyCtrl(SC.SizedPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyCtrl, self).__init__(parent)

        tx1 = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        tx1.SetSizerProps(expand=True, proportion=1)
        tx2 = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        tx2.SetSizerProps(expand=True, proportion=1)


class MyFrame(SC.SizedFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent,
                                       style=wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)

        pane = self.GetContentsPane()
        st = wx.StaticText(pane, label='Text')

        sp = SC.SizedScrolledPanel(pane)
        sp.SetSizerProps(expand=True, proportion=1)
        mc1 = MyCtrl(sp)
        mc2 = MyCtrl(sp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import wx.lib.mixins.inspection as WIT
    app = WIT.InspectableApp()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```